# Identify this type of graph puzzle

Tags: graph-theory, puzzle-identification

There are $V-1$ pieces, each with an identifying symbol. The board is a graph with $V$ vertices and some number of edges $E$. The idea is to move around the pieces so that each piece's symbol matches the underlying vertex's symbol. You can only move a piece if it is connected to the empty vertex by an edge. One of the vertices is blank (no symbol) since there is one more vertex than pieces. Is there a name for this type of puzzle?

[image: Picture of puzzle]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you put the question into a graph theory context, the most appropriate name for these games might be "[(Labeled) Pebble Motion Problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pebble_motion_problems)", those being the generalisation of the [15 puzzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/15_puzzle) onto arbitrary graph and piece configurations.

Comment: Thank you as well! That is a very specific name and I am happy to see a Wikipedia article about it. Thus I am making this the accepted answer.

Comment: @Bass neat, I didn't know that these had a "name"! Good to know.

Answer (score 0):

I posted a comment about this, but I think I'll change it into an answer.

I don't actually think there is a "name" to this type of puzzle, but I'll show one specific example of this puzzle where the community has adopted a name for the puzzle.

> That game specifically being the [Nancy Drew game *Labyrinth Of Lies*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nancy_Drew:_Labyrinth_of_Lies). In the game, a slightly different version is used, with $V - 3$ tokens instead of $V - 1$ — but I believe that my answer should still hold. 
>  
>  In many of the 'walkthroughs' of this game, the puzzle is referred to as "The Token Puzzle" or "[The Sliding Token Puzzle](https://youtu.be/o9LmrrX62Ho?t=80)".
>
>  I'm sure that there are many other games that use this type of puzzle, but this is the one I could think of off the top of my head.

Comment: Thank you! I think this is pretty much the same type of puzzle. I saw your comment before you changed it to an answer and you linked to an image of that puzzle - which I think was this one - https://i.ytimg.com/vi/o9LmrrX62Ho/maxresdefault.jpg - including it here for reference.

Comment: @Mixolydian You're welcome! I'm glad I could help.